# How to build a Debian/Ubuntu package from source?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, packaging

I have the source of a program (taken from cvs/svn/git/...) and I'd like to build a Debian/Ubuntu package for it. The package is present in the repositories, but:

- It is an older version (lacking features I need)
- I need slightly different compile options than the default.

What is the easiest way of doing it? I am concerned about a couple of things

- How can I check if I have listed all the dependencies correctly? (I can get some hints by looking on what the older version depended, but new dependencies may have been added.)
- How I can I prevent the update system installing the older version in the repo on an update?
- How I can prevent the system installing a newer version (when its out), overwriting my custom package?

Comment: Similar on AU: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28372/how-do-i-get-the-source-code-of-packages-installed-through-apt-get

Answer (score 81):

you can use the special package "checkinstall" for all packages which are not even in debian/ubuntu yet.

You can use "uupdate" (`apt-get install devscripts`) to build a package from source with existing debian sources:

Example for libdrm2:

```
apt-get build-dep libdrm2
apt-get source libdrm2
cd libdrm-2.3.1
uupdate ~/Downloads/libdrm-2.4.1.tar.gz
cd ../libdrm-2.4.1
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -nc
```

Comment: Thanks! I have just used this to port Subversion 1.6.6 to an Ubuntu install that only has 1.6.5 as its latest available version, and it worked flawlessly. Saved me quite a few hours of tinkering! :)

Comment: Could you give a little more context around these commands? Where is `libdrm-2.3.1` exactly? Also where did `libdrm-2.4.1.tar.gz` come from (my initial assumption is that is the compiled binary of the application that we want to package in a deb, but replacing the existing version, is that correct?)

Comment: If you get the error `You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list`, uncomment the deb-src lines in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 30):

First, the title question:
  Assuming the debian directory is already there, be in the source directory (the directory containing the debian directory) and invoke dpkg-buildpackage.  I like to run it with these options:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -nc
```

which mean don't sign the result and don't clean.

> How can I check if I have listed all the dependencies correctly?

Getting the dependencies is a black art.  The "official" way is to check build depends is if the package builds with only the base system, the "build-essential" packages, and the build dependencies you have specified.  Don't know a general answer for regular Dependencies, just wade in :)

> How I can I prevent the update system installing the older version in the repo on an update?
>   How I can prevent the system installing a newer version (when its out), overwriting my custom package?

My knowledge might be out of date on this one, but to address both:
Use dpkg --set-selections.  Assuming nullidentd was the package you wanted to stay put, run as root

```
echo 'nullidentd hold' | dpkg --set-selections
```

Alternately, since you are building from source, you can use an [epoch](http://www.us.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version) to set the version number artificially high and never be bothered again.  To use an epoch, add a new entry to the debian/changelog file, and put a 99: in front of the version number.  Given my nullidentd example, the first line of your updated changelog would read:

```
nullidentd (99:1.0-4) unstable; urgency=low
```

[Bernard's link](http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/) is good, especially if you have to create the debian directory yourself - also helpful are the [developers reference](http://www.us.debian.org/doc/developers-reference/) and the [general resource page](http://www.us.debian.org/devel/).  [Adam's link](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/) also looks good but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: "dpkg --set-selections" still works, but a better method these days would be "aptitude hold nullidentd".

Answer (score 7):

Sample **Ubuntu-based build** for ccache:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get build-dep ccache
apt-get -b source ccache
sudo dpkg -i ccache*.deb
```

More details: http://blog.aplikacja.info/2011/11/building-packages-from-sources-in-debianubuntu/

Answer (score 6):

For what you want to do, you probably want to use the debian source diff, so your package is similar to the official one apart from the upstream version used. You can download the source diff from [packages.debian.org](http://packages.debian.org), or can get it along with the .dsc and the original source archive by using "apt-get source".

Then you unpack your new version of the upstream source, change into that directory, and apply the diff you downloaded by doing

```
zcat ~/downloaded.diff.gz | patch -p1
chmod +x debian/rules
```

Then make the changes you wanted to compile options, and build the package by doing

```
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe [this](http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/) is the Debian package 'bible'.

Well, it's the Debian new maintainer's guide, so a lot of it won't be applicable, but they do cover what goes where.

Answer (score 3):

- put "debian" directory from original package to your source directory
- use "[dch](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/dch.1.html)" to update version of package
- use "debuild" to build the package

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Ubuntu, check out the pkgcreator project:
http://code.google.com/p/pkgcreator

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/) is a tutorial for building a Debian package.

Basically, you need to:

1. Set up your folder structure
2. Create a **control** file
3. Optionally create **postinst** or **prerm** scripts
4. Run dpkg-deb

I usually do all of this in my Makefile so I can just type **make** to spit out the binary and package it in one go.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I check if I have listed all the dependencies correctly?

The `pbuilder` is an excellent tool for checking both build dependencies and dependencies by setting up a clean base system within a chroot environment. By compiling the package within pbuilder, you can easily check the build dependencies, and by testing it within a pbuilder environment, you can check the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a quick and dirty way of installing the build dependencies, use:

```
apt-get build-dep
```

This installs the dependencies. You need sources lines in your sources.list for this:

```
deb-src http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main contrib non-free
```

If you are backporting packages from testing to stable, please be advised that the dependencies might have changed. The command apt-get build-deb installs dependencies for the source packages in your current repository.

But of course, dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc will show you any uninstalled dependencies.

If you want to compile more often, use cowbuilder.

```
apt-get install cowbuilder
```

Then create a build-area:

sudo DIST=squeeze ARCH=amd64 cowbuilder --create

Then compile a source package:

```
apt-get source cowsay

# do your magic editing
dpkg-source -b cowsay-3.03+dfsg1              # build the new source packages
cowbuilder --build cowsay_3.03+dfsg1-2.dsc    # build the packages from source
```

Watch where cowbuilder puts the resulting package.

Good luck!