# Resources on writing a Debian/Ubuntu deb package?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, debian-based

I'm getting started preparing an installation script for a software package onto an Ubuntu server.  I would like to write a script as a .deb package that is aware of dependencies that must be installed beforehand (a database, web server, etc.).

Can you recommend any tutorials/resources to help a newbie developer get started writing deb packages?

Update: Canonical has a thorough [Packaging Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide) which explains the process very well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are entirely new to building Debian packages, I suggest that you look at the [Debian New Maintainers' Guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/) and use the [Debian Developer's Reference](http://www.debian.org/doc/developers-reference/) as reference. As a starting point, `dh_make` (from the `dh-make` package) should give you a good template to work with.

Answer (score 4):

Earlier question at stackoverflow:
[**How to build a Debian/Ubuntu package from source?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130894/how-to-build-a-debian-ubuntu-package-from-source)

- The [HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/),
- [another article](http://users.telenet.be/mydotcom/howto/linux/package.htm).
- [Creating packages for personal use](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PythonRecipes/DebianPackage) (not for repositories)
- UbuntuForum discussion on creating [static packages](http://swiss.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=7609692)

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to install some software with their dependencies, you don't really need to make a .deb package. A Shell script should work, calling the package manager to resolve dependencies, etc.

The default Shell on Ubuntu is Bash. If you don't know how to do it, here is a [basic tutorial](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html) and an [advanced guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: The reason I want to do a deb is that we will be creating many of these servers over time, and I'd like to distribute updates via this mechanism.  I imagine I'll be using bash scripts within the installer to carry out steps of the installation.  Thanks for the help!