# compiling lighttpd with default config options

Tags: linux, compilation, apt

I am about to compile lighttpd. And i would like to know if there is a command that shows the array of options with witch the program will be compiled if I choose the default?

```
./configure
```

In fact I seen in ./configure --help that there are some of them default, but I like to have the complete list

In another way : is the result of

```
apt-get source lighttpd
./configure
make
make install
make clean
```

the same think like

```
apt-get install lighttpd
```

Comment: Try dpkg-buildpackage. See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130894/how-to-build-a-debian-ubuntu-package-from-source

Comment: Definitely not, for example, the default prefix is `/usr/local`, but in packages installed with `apt-get` it usually is `/usr`.

Comment: how can I find out with what option the official version has been compiled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do is to find the build log corresponding to your release. For example for ubuntu saucy the [build log](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/153818628/buildlog_ubuntu-saucy-amd64.lighttpd_1.4.31-3ubuntu3_UPLOADING.txt.gz) of lighttpd shows

```
dh_auto_configure -- \
            --disable-dependency-tracking \
            --libdir=/usr/lib/lighttpd \
            --libexecdir="/usr/lib/lighttpd" \
            --with-attr \
            --with-fam \
            --with-gdbm \
            --with-kerberos5 \
            --with-ldap \
            --with-lua=lua5.1 \
            --with-memcache \
            --with-mysql \
            --with-openssl \
            --with-pcre \
            --with-webdav-locks \
            --with-webdav-props \
    CFLAGS="-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security" CPPFLAGS="-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2" CXXFLAGS="-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security" FFLAGS="-g -O2" LDFLAGS="-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro"
```