# (Incremental) Rebuild Debian/Ubuntu package

Tags: ubuntu, build, compilation, package, debian

I'm following the instructions at the [how to build a Debian package from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130894/how-to-build-a-debian-ubuntu-package-from-source) question successfully.

However, I want to repeatedly rebuild the package after making modifications to the source (a "incremental build"), and the suggested commands do rebuild the package, but the modified source files are not recompiled.

How can I make `dpkg-buildpackage` (or `debian/rules`) rebuild modified source files? Is this possible to achieve generically, or does it depend on the package build file?

Specifically, I'm trying to do this for the `chromium-browser` package

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question was found on https://askubuntu.com/a/2879/164798

In short:

- `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -nc` uses the full toolchain
- `fakeroot debian/rules binary` just does the compile step

You need to execute it from the package source directory (where the `debian/` directory lives).

## Notes on how to get started with the Debian build system:

- For upstream packages download all 3 files: `.dsc`, `.orig.tar.gz` (or `.xz` etc.), `.diff.gz` (or `.xz`, etc.).
- For native packages download all 2 files: `.dsc`, `.tar.gz` (or `.xz` etc.)
- If it is in `apt` you can do `apt-get source "$PACKAGE"`, this also includes the next step (it runs `dpkg-source -x` for you).

Unpack the source:

- `dpkg-source -x "$FULLPACKAGE.dsc"` where `FULLPACKAGE` is the full package name (including full version)

Compile the first time:

- `cd "$ORIGPACKAGE"` where `ORIGPACKAGE` is like `FULLPACKAGE` with the version only up to the first dash (`-`)
- Now run `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -nc`
- If you see `Unmet build dependencies:` (see also `dpkg-checkbuilddeps`):

  - Either try `apt-get build-dep $PACKAGE` if you can use `apt`.  If not:
  - Look into `debian/control` for the `Build-Depends` and install the dependencies.  If you want to automate this
  - `mk-build-deps -i "$FULLPACKAGE.dsc" -t sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends -y` (found there: https://www.v13.gr/blog/?p=364).
  - If you cannot use this (build for different architecture etc.) then try `pbuilder` (sorry, I do not know anything about this yet)

To quick compile changes afterwards:

- Use `fakeroot debian/rules binary`

If you are happy with it use `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc` (and leave the options away if you use signing).

Comment: In my case "binary" will also create the packages. But the command "dh_auto_install" will just make the binary.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your source code, the build tool used should take care of compiling freshly modified source files. The debian packaging tools call the build tool, maybe a Makefile in your case, and build a package from the generated binary and other artefacts.

In general packaging should be a late step in your software development process. First write the code and then package it when ready for release.

I recommend using pbuilder to do the package building in a virtual container on your system, rather than on the system itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git [hooks](http://githooks.com/) with [git-buildpackage](https://honk.sigxcpu.org/piki/projects/git-buildpackage/) on a fork of the debian git [repository](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-chromium/pkg-chromium.git) to help automate this.