# Installing a python apt package to conda env

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, anaconda, nvidia, apt

I'm trying to install a specific version of [NVIDIA's `python3-libnvinfer` (TensorRT)](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/install-guide/index.html) to a specific version of [an AWS deep learning container](https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers/blob/master/available_images.md).

Unfortunately, that image is based on Ubuntu 16.04 with Python 3.6 managed by Anaconda and `apt` has separately installed Python 3.5. When I try to `apt-get install libnvinfer-plugin6=6.0.1-1+cuda10.1` it installs to the Python 3.5 environment vs the Python 3.6 environment I need to use.

```
root@beast:/app# python3 --version
Python 3.6.13 :: Anaconda, Inc.
root@beast:/app# which python
/opt/conda/bin/python
root@beast:/app# locate tensorrt | grep python
/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorrt
```

NVIDIA's `pip` install method only works with CUDA 11.3 but I'm pinned to CUDA 10.1 due to other dependencies and those dependencies will not work with Python 3.5:

```
The pip-installable nvidia-tensorrt Python wheel files only support Python versions
3.5 to 3.9 and CUDA 11.3 at this time and will not work with other Python or CUDA versions.
```

Is there any way to tell `apt` to install the package to the conda version of python (3.6) vs the apt version of python (3.5)?

Comment: I don't think there is a sane way to satisfy this. As you have noticed, `apt` requires all dependencies to also be managed by `apt`. Similarly, there is no easy way to convince Conda that you have installed a paokage by other means with all the depencencies Conda expects to be satisfied; these different architectures also sometimes require conformant packages to implement additional behaviors, sometimes even to the point where compatibility with the upstream has to be sacrificed.

Comment: There are hacks like `equivs` which let you convince Apt that a package is in fact installed, but it is only really suitable for quick and dirty fixes, not for building a complex and robust alternative solution.

Comment: Having said that, it might be feasible to compile and package your own `.deb` for version 3.6 of Python based on the source package for 3.5.

Comment: It looks like the "build from source" option actually builds a pip wheel, not the `.deb`. I know pip works to install dependencies to the right python in this image so I'm going to try that route next.

Comment: You probably misunderstood what I tried to say.  You would download the package source with `apt-get source packagename` and then edit the scripts to package a different version with your own dependencies.

Comment: @tripleee could you give more details on the steps after `apt-get source packagename` necessary to install `packagename` into a conda environment?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130894/how-to-build-a-debian-ubuntu-package-from-source for how to build from source. You are then free to install that package anywhere; I'm not particularly familiar with Conda, but this bypasses that anyway.